# How to remove unwanted indentation when trying to display code in html with <pre> tag?

Tags: html, laravel-blade, editorjs

I'm trying to display code in laravel blade template write with editorjs using `<pre><code>....</code></pre>` and i want to ask : why the first line in the displayed code has this big indentation ?

[Click to see the render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0O6X.png)

Down below is my code :

```
@if ($content->type == 'code')
    <pre class="w-full m-0">
        <code class="block text-left p-4 border border-solid border-gray-500 bg-gray-100 rounded-md">
            {{ $content->data->code }}
        </code>
    </pre>
    <br>
@endif
```

I already tried to remove the `<pre></pre>` tag and keep `<code></code>` tag. The indentation disapear but with the other normal indentation. Tried to remove margin : no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can right-click in the browser and click "inspect" or "inspect element". It will open the developer console where it shows you paddings, margins and all css affecting the display.

Comment: Resolved : pre tag takes into account the lesser character such as spaces or line breaks. In my case, the problem was that in my code I had a line break in the <pre> tag xD

Comment: Okay that would do it : ) You may answer your own question BTW so it's not listed in the open questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally resolved: The pre tag takes into account the lesser character such as spaces or line breaks. In my case, the problem was that in my code I had a line break in the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Joyce, if you replace your answer with what you posted in your comment, you'll have a valid answer for others to upvote, and you'll also be able to answer your own question by clicking the check box. As it currently stands, you are likely to have your answer downvoted or removed.